# Let $v_{1}=(1,-2,3),v_{2}=(0,-1,2)$. Enlarge $\{v_{1},v_{2}\}$ to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra

For instance, let $v_{1}=(1,-2,3),v_{2}=(0,-1,2)$. The set $\{v_{1},v_{2}\}$ is linearly independent. Enlarging $\{v_{1},v_{2}\}$ to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ I simply form a matrix using $v_{1},v_{2}$ as columns and then augment one of the elementary columns from $I_{3}$ and see whether the resulting echelon form has $3$ pivots, from then I conclude that it spans $\mathbb{R}^3$ and is linearly independent.

But the book I am using gives a solution as: $(a,b,c)$ with $9a-3b-5c\neq 0$. What method was use here and how might I arrive at such an answer? Thanks.

Comment: i get (1,3,0) as linearly independent. what's the book?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Howard Anton's Elementary Linear Algebra. He doesn't give an example of his method for enlarging a set of vectors to a basis though.

Comment: I think the book's answer should read: " Any vector $(a,b,c)$ such that $9a-3b-5c \neq 0$ will form with the other two vectors a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ ." The question was not to give a formula for all such verctors, but to give one vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$S=\{(1,-2,3),(0,-1,2),(a,b,c)\}$ will be basis iff

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & a \\
        -2 & -1 & b \\
        3 & 2 & c \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ has rank $3$, and matrix will have rank $3$ iff determinant of the matrix is nozero, hence

$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 0 & a \\
        -2 & -1 & b \\
        3 & 2 & c \\
        \end{vmatrix}\neq0$$

$$\Rightarrow a+2b+c\neq0$$

Comment: You can also reduce the above matrix in Echelon form to get the required condition.

Answer (score 2):

Since $v_1$ and $v_2$ are obviously linearly independent you can take $v_3:=v_1\times v_2$ (cross product), which is a vector orthogonal to the plane spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Answer (score 1):

You could compute the determinant of the matrix with the columns $v_1$, $v_2$, and $(a, b, c)$. However, I got a different condition on $a,b,c$.

Comment: Can you share what you got anyways?

Comment: @Math2555: I got $-7a -2b -c \ne 0$.

Comment: @Math2555 oh I found my error. sorry, .@chiranjeev is right.